# sendRedirect does not redirect to correct URL

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jetty

I'm trying to produce a servlet that sends a redirect after entering details into a database. The URL that I want to redirect to is on a different subdomain and I'm using the response.sendRedirect(String URL) method in my servlet. The servlet is hosted at http://resources.example.com/.

Currently, I'm using this: (which is a servlet hosted on a tomcat at http://resources.example.com)

```
private static String action;
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    action = getAction(request.getRequestURI());
        if(action.equals("register")){
            try {
                new User(request.getParameter("name"), request.getParameter("email")).commit();
                response.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com/success.html");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                response.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com/error.html");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                response.sendRedirect("http://www.example.com/error.html");
            }
        }
```

but instead of redirecting to http://www.example.com/error.html, it is redirecting to http://resources.example.com/error.html.

Seeing that I am using a fully formed URL, I would expect this redirect to work. Is there any way of sending a redirect to http://www.example.com/error.html instead of http://resources.example.com.

I should note that when I have the servlet hosted locally (at localhost) and I send the redirect to http://www.example.com, it seems to work correctly.

I am using Jetty and I have tested with Tomcat 7 and have had the same issue.

Thanks for any help,

Matt

Comment: is it redirect -> redirect case ?

Comment: is this url loading in a browser http://www.example.com/error.html . Also check the response headers when you send a request to this servlet url, through firebug or developer tools.

Comment: @JigarJoshi No, it is just a simple redirect to a page in a different sub-domain.

Comment: Is is cross domain issue?

Comment: I've just used [link](http://example.com) for the sake of this example, but I'm just sending the default response headers for a redirect, I think it's 307.

Comment: @Braj yes, to a different subdomain.

Comment: try avoiding `http://www.` , not sure if it will help.

Comment: @Subin That redirected to: [http://resources.example.com/example.com/error.html](http://example.com/example.com/error.html)

Comment: I have tried with `http://www.google.com` and its redirecting properly. Test it at your end.

Comment: same here tested it out and redirecting properly, may be post the full servlet code? is it throwing any exception?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the most of the servlet and the doGet method. (and it isn't throwing any exception)

Comment: please `return` after `response.sendRedirect`

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. Would my server be the issue, a Jetty 9.1.2 container running on Windows Azure (I'm guessing on Windows Server).

Comment: not sure, atleast it works in local env for you. It should work in server as well.

Comment: Sure, [http://mbowtiqueres.azurewebsites.net/](http://mbowtiqueres.azurewebsites.net/) is where the servlet is hosted, so a request would be http://mbowtiqueres.azurewebsites.net/_a/register?name=ExampleName&email=blah@blah.com which should redirect to: http://mbowtique.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: It seems it redirects to `http://mbowtiqueres.azurewebsites.net/error.html` there has been an exception in your `new User` line.

Comment: But the problem is that it should redirect to http://mbowtique.azurewebsites.net/error.html. The error is expected.